# Is it possible to create simple CRUD example using Fixture Adapter in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We've been trying to implement simple CRUD example using Fixture Adapter for a few days but it seems that what feels like a walk in the park using RestAdapter, is almost impossible with Fixture one. And I mean relations.

Here's a live example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zobexuhi/3

Flow:
1) Contact Edit / New (not finished)

• emails are not saved immediately but only using 'Save' button
• Cancel reverts changes (`rollback`)
• not persisted data does not appear in contacts#index

What we've tried so far

• hasMany loses data on save - we extended json serializer / used canary built (don't know why but recent change broke this again)

• with the above we encountered another problem - on save a duplicate of email was created even though the store had only one instance - we tried to return unique data using `uniq()`

We've been trying to fix these problems for at least three days and the more solution we tried, the deeper the black hole was.

This example is (was?) supposed to be an app that we'd like to use as example how to write ambitious web apps using BDD approach. As some of you may notice it is based on 'Testing Ember.js in Rails' book.

This is not a rant. We'd like to do these workshops, but using Fixture Adapter we've failed so far.

We're aware that many things are wrong in this example, but getting back from RestAdapter to Fixture one (not tested) is always a pain in the ass for us.

Any feedback will be highly appreciated!